# C++ How can I ignore symbols/numbers in a text file when reading it into a string?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, count, words

I'm working on a project where I need to make a word counter that counts the unique words in a text file. In class, we just learned about STL, and we're supposed to make the program using a map. What I have reads in the words from the file and counts them accurately, except that it doesn't ignore symbols or numbers, which I need it to do. For example, as it is now, it counts the words "file" and "file." as two separate words. How can I fix that? The other issue I'm having is that the words should be printed in alphabetical order. This is what i have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class words, class counter>
void PrintMap(map<words, counter> map)
{
    typedef std::map<words, counter>::iterator iterator;
    for (iterator p = map.begin(); p != map.end(); p++)
    cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << endl;
}

int main()
{
    static const char* fileName = "D:\\MyFile.txt";

    map<string, int> wordCount;
    {
        ifstream fileStream(fileName);

        if (fileStream.is_open())
            while (fileStream.good())
            {
                string word;
                fileStream >> word;

                if (wordCount.find(word) == wordCount.end())
                    wordCount[word] = 1;
                else
                    wordCount[word]++;
            }
        else 
        {
            cerr << "Couldn't open the file." << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        PrintMap(wordCount);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle, Jake Killpack's answer is right. You can either read the string and then trim it *or* you adjust the behaviour on how the strings are read in C++. According to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt):

> [`operator >>`] [...] then reads characters from is and appends them to str as if by
>   str.append(1, c), until one of the following conditions becomes true:
>
> - [...]
> - std::isspace(c,is.getloc()) is true for the next character c in is    (this whitespace character remains in the input stream).

Clearly, punctuations are no whitespace, so they get read and added to the word as well. For this to change, you have to adjust the behaviour of `std::isspace` s.t. it treats punctuation as whitespace, which can be done, even though it's awkward:

```
struct punctws_ctype : std::ctype<char> {
    static const mask* table() {
        static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);
        v[','] |= space; // classify comma as whitespace
        v['.'] |= space; // accordingly...
        v['-'] |= space;
        return &v[0];
    }

    my_ctype(std::size_t refs = 0) : std::ctype<char>{ table(), false, refs } { } 
};
```

And later, before you read on the stream:

```
// apply the modified behaviour to the stream:
fileStream.imbue(std::locale{ fileStream.getloc(), new my_ctype });
```

Now, when reading with `fileStream >> word`, it will strip any punctuations right away.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a separate function to get rid of the symbols you don't want in each string before you check it in your wordCount dictionary. For example, after you read a new word you could run a little trim function that goes character by character through the word to see if any character == a '.' or '-' etc.